# The product of xy of two real numbers x and y is irrational then at least one of the x or y must be irrational.

Tags: irrational-numbers

Prove if true or find a counterexample....

The product of $x y $ of two real numbers $x$ and $y$ is irrational then at least one of the $x$ or $y$ must be irrational.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507865/check-if-this-proof-about-real-numbers-with-an-irrational-product-is-correct

Comment: For many questions you will find that restating the proposition by [contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) will clear up the issue.  See the Answer by @mich95 for its application to your Question.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $x$ and $y$ are rationals, then so is $xy$. That's the contrapositive of your proposition!

Comment: We were within $6$ seconds of each other! I'll delete my answer. $+1$